# i don't know how to work with command argument in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

i'm tryng to pass a parameter with command argument with a link button but the result i get is always "".

this is in my aspx page:

```
<%
LinkButton1.CommandArgument = "abcdef";                                 
%>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand= "LinkButton1_Click">
```

and in my aspx.cs i have:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender,CommandEventArgs ee)
{
    String id = ee.CommandName.ToString();
}
```

the id is always "" after i press the linkbutton.

would appreciate if someone could help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at my dev machine but it would be more like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
    CommandArgument="abcdef" OnCommand="LinkButton1_Click" >
```

And then check `CommandArgument` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton id="LinkButton1" 
           Text="Order Item 10001"
           CommandName="Order" 
           CommandArgument="10001" 
           OnCommand="LinkButton_Command" 
           runat="server"/>
```

From the example at [LinkButton.CommandArgument Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument.aspx).

Comment: like this it works, but what if i wanna write it like <%
LinkButton1.CommandArgument = "abcdef";                                 
%>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnCommand= "LinkButton1_Click"> ? Why dosen't it work?

Comment: @Depozitul: because that's not how Microsoft designed it. ASP.NET doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the CommandArgument in your aspx, but checking the CommandName in your event handler.